# jQuery.bind() doesn´t respond to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a block of jQuery like this :

```
jqObj.bind('change', function () {
      debugger;
    });
```

`jqObj` matches two elements (dropDownList), but only the first of them respond to the 'change' event, the second element that on position [1] do nothing on change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please create an isolated but complete code example to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Try this and see if you have same issue. `$('body').on('change', '#id1, #id2', function() { debugger; });` @AntonSelin

Comment: There can be two different reasons for this, either that bind is called before the element is created therefore not captured by the selector or that the 'change' event does not get triggered when you think it is for the element. check the previous comment for the solution to the first alternative.

Comment: the second element is created dynamically, but the jqObj is chenged when new element is created.

Comment: and i also cannot use the .on() because my jQuery is 1.6 version, when the .on() is integrated only in 1.7 version or later

Comment: what is the selector you have used to get 'jqObj' object? If it is Id then id should not be duplicate ... use classes as selector

Comment: if your using 1.6 you can use .live